# Calling feed parsing from web autodecode Punycode for IDN in .NET

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii, idn, punycode

I have RSS feed 
http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/feeds
When I add this feed via Web ASP.Net MVC App and call method for parsing feed, feed properties are auto-converted from ASCII to Unicode representation in properties.
When I call same code from Windows Forms it remains ASCII represented in properties.

I do want to remain ASCII represented URL-s parsed from FEED. 
I don't know how this can happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution.
It seams that it is related to web.config settings

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
  <idn enabled="All" />
  <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```